# What if you get denied entry into the US while holding a residence permit for studies in Europe?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, removal, deportation

I am a student visa holder in Europe with a US B1/B2 visa. I am originally from Sri Lanka and I was wondering that if I travel to US and in the unlikely scenario that I get denied entry by the CBP, where will I be sent off to? Back to Sri Lanka or back to Europe where I hold residence permit for studies?

Comment: Travel from where? If from Europe likely to Europe since you have a permit. If from Sri Lanka, back to Sri Lanka.

Answer (score 1):

You're sent back to where you flew from, provided you can enter that country.

So in your case, it would be to Europe.